# Result Page not opening in Target Frame whenever clicked on Tabs using Jquery. Opens in the Same Frame

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am Using 2 Horizontle Frames. In Top Frame I used Jquery Tabs. I expect Whenever I click on The tab , the result Page should open in the below Frame. But It Is not working. Can anybody help me plz. Do Jquery Tabs Supports Frames?

Comment: please post the code are you using to initialize the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="80,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="top.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frame src="cont.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
<noframes><body>
</body>
</noframes></html>
```

top.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

$(function(){

    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert( $(window.parent.document.frames["mainFrame"].document).find("body").html() );
        $(window.parent.document.frames["mainFrame"].document).find("body").html("<div>this is a test</div>");
        alert( $(window.parent.document.frames["mainFrame"].document).find("body").html() );
    }); 
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

cont.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>empty</div>
</body>
</html>
```